# Why Doesn't @DocumentID Allow For Updates On List Row When Used As ID Parameter?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am working on a SwiftUI Project and using Firestore as a backend. I am using @DocumentID to as the id property for my objects. I noticed that when I use the id to identify the item in a List/ForEach as part of a view, the row does not update if I update the object in Firebase. If change the id property to a String and remove the @DocumentID property wrapper then updates to the object in Firestore update the row.

The only thing I can think of is that when you use @DocumentID the property becomes the name of the document and the property is not stored in the document. When using a String the property is stored in the document. Below I have the code that uses @DocumentID and the String.

**Listing.swift - Model - Using @DocumentID - Rows Don't Update When The Database Updates**

```
struct Listing: Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String
    var description: String
}
```

**Listing.swift - Model - Using String - Rows Update When The Database Updates**

```
struct Listing: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var description: String
}
```

**ListingRowViewModel.swift**

This file assigns the id to an id variable on the ListingRowViewModel. The ListingRowViewModels used in the ForEach loop for the list.

```
class ListingRowViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var id: String = ""
    @Published var listing: Listing
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init(listing: Listing) {
        self.listing = listing
        
        $listing
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .compactMap { listing in
                listing.id
            }
            .assign(to: \.id, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

**List & ForEach Used in View**

```
List {
    ForEach(self.marketplaceViewModel.listingRowViewModels, id: \.id) { listingRowViewModel in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ListingDetailView(listingDetailViewModel: ListingDetailViewModel(listing: listingRowViewModel.listing))) {
                        ListingRowView(listing: listingRowViewModel.listing)
                    }
                }
}
```

Is there a way to use the @DocumentID property wrapper and allow for updates to the row data when the object is updated in Firestore?

Comment: I haven't had any issues with `@DocumentID`, `Identifiable`, and `List` so far (actually using this all of the time). In fact, you probably don't need the `id: \.id` parameter in the `List`. I would recommend mapping *all* documents in a loop and then assign the result to a published collection property on your `marketplaceViewModel`. BTW - now that I write this - is `listingRowViewModels` marked as `@Published`?

Comment: @PeterFriese Wow! I'm quite honored you're answering this. I love your work and have followed your YouTube tutorials and love them. I found the issue. I was not observing a listingRowViewModel in ListingRowView. Now this works. And yes, listingRowViewModels are marked as {@Published}. I am going to read your blog. It seems to have expanded on the video. I am currently using an {@EnvironmentObject} for MarketplaceViewModel but Resolver looks interesting. Please keep up the excellent work. What you're adding to the SwiftUI/Firebase/Combine community is extremely helpful for folks like me.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, Jon - always good to see our work is useful for the community!